# How to push string to array based on input field number value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to push `string` into array based on the number that user has put in the field?

Scenario: If the user add an item into the basket, the `function()` will push the SKU string into the array which is fine but when the user update the qty of the item in the basket (say he/she updated the qty to 5) then it also should pushed 5 SKU strings into the array list.

Is this possible by any chance?

I thought it'd be simple as the code below using a unary operator to make the string as number, but that's just a sample but this returns a `NaN` I supposed because skuField is a string

e.g SKU `321005Y-00100-ITM`

```
console.log('Push sku based on qtyField ', [item.qtyField + (+item.skuField)]);
```

E.g Object:-- so this is what my object looks like when an item is added into the basket with qty of 3.

```
var updateCartItem = {
    Products: [
  {  
       "product_idField":"96031",
       "skuField":"321005Y-00100-ITM",
       "nameField":"Cooper Sunglasses",
       "priceField":"75.0000",
       "qtyField":3,
       "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
       "$$hashKey":"object:8"
    }
 ]
}
```

Code: --

```
for (var i = 0; i < updateCartItem.Products.length; i++) {
     var element = updateCartItem.Products[i];
  console.log([element.skuField]) // this will only push 1 sku (should be 3)
}
```

So based on the `qtyField: 3`, I expect to have `["321005Y-00100-ITM", "321005Y-00100-ITM", "321005Y-00100-ITM"]`. If `qtyField` value is 5 or 100, then the array string should have whatever the `qtyField` value is.

Comment: *"Is this possible by any chance?"* of course. You can simply loop from `0` to the quantity entered and push a value to the array inside the loop. You can learn more about loops at http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_rDxYNPd65Z .

Comment: This sounds like something you should be using an object for, rather than an array of strings. Example: order = { SKU: { name, quantity, ...any other info },... }. That way you can simply do order[SKU string here].quantity = newQuantity

Comment: _"then it also should pushed 5 SKU strings into the array list"_ - no, it should not. It should increment the number of times this items is ordered. That is _one_ value, that you store _one_ time.

Comment: @CBroe, yes I understand that. There's a reason why I'm pushing SKU instead of updating the number. I need the SKU for POS injection which expect SKU code not the qty value.

Comment: I've added a sample JSON in my question and expected result.

Comment: So the expected result would be that the `skuField` of that object is an array, instead of a string value? Well then make it an array, where is the problem with that?

Comment: My problem is when I push SKU in array `[]` the array would only have 1 SKU, the array sku string values should be whatever the QTY: value is. In my example I have QTY: 3, so I expect to have 3 sku sting values (not object) in the array.

Comment: just use a `for`-loop with ending index = qty. And in the loop, push the required element (that string) to the array ...

Comment: @KarelG, sorry I don't quite follow. I've added the code im using above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want. I have added two another products, the first one has `qty=3` (your example), 2nd has `qty=1` and 3th one has no qty (added by myself).

I have introduced a function `getArrayFrom(...)` (rename it if you wish) which returns an array of the `skuField` names based on the number of `qty` value.

```js
var updateCartItem = {
    Products: [
  {  
       "product_idField":"96031",
       "skuField":"321005Y-00100-ITM",
       "nameField":"Cooper Sunglasses",
       "priceField":"75.0000",
       "qtyField":3,
       "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
       "$$hashKey":"object:8"
    },
      {  
       "product_idField":"another",
       "skuField":"another-ITM",
       "nameField":"Pony Sunglasses",
       "priceField":"75.0000",
       "qtyField":1,
       "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
       "$$hashKey":"object:8"
    },
    {  
       "product_idField":"empty",
       "skuField":"empty-ITM",
       "nameField":"Nobody wants it Sunglasses",
       "priceField":"75.0000",
       "qtyField":0,
       "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
       "$$hashKey":"object:8"
    }
 ]
}

function getArrayFrom(product) {
    const arr = [];
    if (product && product.qtyField) {
        for(var i = 0; i < product.qtyField; ++i) arr.push(product.skuField);
    }
    return arr;
}

for(var i = 0; i < updateCartItem.Products.length; ++i) {
    var element = updateCartItem.Products[i];
    console.log('product: ' + element.nameField + ' has array ', getArrayFrom(element));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply to your answer, yes something like that but if you already have a string in the array, then if you add more based on the qty then the `length` of the array is +1. Is there a way to avoid the array.length to be 1 ahead and should sync to the `qtyField`. To illustrate my question https://plnkr.co/edit/HBiVAphYSHGXjP4aYYzu?p=preview

Comment: @MrNew That's what I did. Check the for loop. It goes through your products. And calls `getArrayFrom(product)`. There, it generates the array based on qty

Comment: Yeah but what if a string value is already existed in the `arr["skuValue"]`, check the plnkr console.

Comment: @MrNew https://plnkr.co/edit/XOufES5W9MZlKaWuF9cs?p=preview  if you don't want that an existing array is modified, just create a new array inside the `getArrayFrom` function and return it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're asking,

you can not use a String as an Index in an array.
On the other hand, you can use an object.

Objects are "arrays with String indexes"

e.g.

```
var objectArray = {"321005Y-00100-ITM": 1};
```

is the same with

```
var objectArray["321005Y-00100-ITM"] = 1
```

If you want to change change the quantity, just pass the number into the "array"

```
var objectArray["321005Y-00100-ITM"] = 5
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: I think your understanding is the other way around, I didn't want to change the quantity. I want the quantity to be the based of how many SKU string I need to push into array. QTY 5 = 5 SKU string.

Comment: @mrnew thats an xy problem. Your data structure does not fit to arrays. Going with this answer would he the best way...

Comment: I added the expected result in my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused with what exactly you want to do.
I agree with **Jonas w**

Comment: @P.Iakovakis so if I have `qtyField: 3`, then my array should have skuField of the item 3x like `["321005Y-00100-ITM", "321005Y-00100-ITM", "321005Y-00100-ITM"]`. If `qtyField` is 4-100, then the array should have whatever the QTY value is. I have no idea how else I could explain this, I've added my code in my question.